# Complicated SQL Search for duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server database looking like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID  |  A  |  B  |  C  |
+=====+=====+=====+=====+
|  1  |  1  |  1  |  6  |
|  2  |  1  |  2  |  7  |
|  3  |  1  |  3  |  3  |
|  4  |  2  |  1  |  6  |
|  5  |  2  |  2  |  7  |
|  6  |  2  |  3  |  8  |
|  7  |  3  |  1  |  6  |
|  8  |  3  |  2  |  9  |
|  9  |  3  |  3  | 10  |
| 10  |  4  |  4  |  4  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

In this table I need to extract Column A values, for which there are multiple duplicates with different A value, but equal B and C values. Meaning that in the above table ID 1 matches ID 4 and ID 7. Further ID 2 matches ID 5, A 1 and A 2 will have more than one common dataset and thus need to be extracted. However A 3 only have one in common with the others, so that should not be extracted.

I hope that someone could help me with this issue as I have not found any simple way to do this.

Comment: why don't you jus post the required output rather than explaining?

Comment: This is a trivial join, no? The effective cross-product filter is `where t1.a <> t2.a and t1.b = t2.b and t1.c = t2.c` (a group by .. having might also be relevant)

Comment: @user2864740 that might be - maybe I am just to tired to see the solution, but you are right. The only issue is that I also need only to extract the situations, where the match is above a certain count. But the again - with the join you suggested it is just adding a count and having clause. Thanks for opening my eyes :-)

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi sorry - i found it easier to explain it.

Comment: @MikkelKongsfelt - Unfortunately, most of the rest of us will have an easier time with an explicit results set.  You should get to used to specifying them anyways - if you're doing any sort of testing, your **tools** will require a result set.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse you are completely right - I will think about that in the future. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that works with repeated values, [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96cbd/11)

```
SELECT
      [t].[id], [t].[a], [t].[b], [t].[c]
  FROM 
      [Temp] [t]
    JOIN (
      SELECT
            [b], [c]
        FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT
                [a], [b], [c]
            FROM
                [Temp]) [deduplicated]
        GROUP BY
            [b], [c]
        HAVING
            count([a]) > 1) [r]
    ON [r].[b] = [t].[b] AND [r].[c] = [t].[c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the below query.?

and
please tell me if i have missed out something.

```
declare @tab1 table (id int,a int,b int, c int)
insert into @tab1 values (1,1,1,6),(2,1,2,7),(3,1,3,3),(4,2,1,6),(5,2,2,7),(6,2,3,8),(7,3,1,6),(8,3,2,9),(9,3,3,10),(10,4,4,4)
 select * from @tab1
```

Code Part

```
 select 
 min(tem.id) id,min(tem.a) a,
 tem.b,tem.c
  from
 (
 select 
  x.* 
 from 
 @tab1 x
  where x.b in (select b from @tab1 y where y.a <> x.a)
  and x.c in (select c from @tab1 y where y.a <> x.a)
  ) tem
group by tem.b,tem.c
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt that `MIN(tem.a)` is always going to match `MIN(tem.id)` (that is, they're on the same row).  The sample data has this, but it's not something I'd take as guaranteed.

Comment: i have used the min() because i hope that @dpk had an requirement like getting only the initial sequence of data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. but this is using oracle as i don't have much idea of SQL server. so you `can convert following Oracle SQl to SQL Server`

```
SELECT A
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT a.*
  FROM temp2 a,
    temp2 b
  WHERE b.b = a.b
  AND b.c   = a.c
  AND b.a  != a.a
  )
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(A)>1;
```

Comment: Well, the query only uses SQL Standard features, so it's fine from that regard.  Unfortunately, you've got some syntax errors in there (at least for SQL Server, and I suspect Oracle as well).  Regardless: 1) please don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause), always explicitly list your joins; 2) Always explicitly list your columns.

Comment: it works perfectly with oracle. and also gives desired output i.e. only 1 and 2 from column A.

Answer (score 0):

The general form of the query is this:

```
SELECT data.id, data.a, data.b, data.c
FROM Temp data
JOIN (SELECT b, c
      FROM Temp
      GROUP BY b, c
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) count
  ON count.b = data.b
     AND count.c = data.c
```

([Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96cbd/4/0))

There's a couple more variations on this, depending on what refinements you need; however, since you didn't give an explicit set of what you wanted (result rows, rows deleted, or whatever), this solution will get you:

```
id  a  b  c
=============
1   1  1  6 
4   2  1  6 
7   3  1  6 
2   1  2  7 
5   2  2  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement, can get the result by using `CTE`.

here is the query.

```
 with cte(id,a,b,c,dupcount) as
 (
    select id,a,b,c,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by b,c order by a desc)  from tab
 )

 select id,a,b,c from cte where dupcount > 1 order by id
```

Its done.